# SVD Decomposition for specific matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

Let's do the SVD decomposition and have $M= U\Sigma V^*$.

Is it true, that for any matrix $M$, which is such that an arithmetic mean in every column is equal to $0$, we get that columns in the matrix $U$ has to have the same proporty (means in columns will be $0$)?

In few cases I noticed this fact, but I don't know if is any general result.

If that is true, can we get a similar result for another means? (not necessarily for $0$ - as the value of the means)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if $M$ has linearly indepent rows. Say $M$ is a $m\times n$ real matrix, then $rank(M)=m$ suffices.

Let $\alpha ^T = (1,1,...,1)$ be a $m$-dimensional vector. Then the condition that arithmetic mean in every column is equal to $0$ is equivalent to
$$\alpha ^TM=(\alpha ^T \beta_1,\alpha ^T \beta_2,...,\alpha ^T \beta_n)=(0,0,...,0)=\mathbf0_{1\times n}$$
where $(\beta_1,\beta_2,...,\beta_n)$ are columns of $M$.

By singular value decomposition, $M=U\Sigma V^*$, then
$$\alpha^TM=\alpha^TU\Sigma V^*=\mathbf0$$
Right-multiplying both sides by $V$, we obtain
$$\alpha^TU\Sigma=\mathbf0\quad(*)$$
The $m\times n$ matrix $\Sigma$ has the same rank as $M$ (this is a property of SVD). Hence $rank(\Sigma) = m$. Then there exists a $n \times m$ matrix $X$ such that
$$\Sigma X=I_m$$
where $I_m$ denotes $m\times m$ identity matrix. Right-multiplying $(*)$ by $X$,
we have $$\alpha ^T U=0$$
Thus the means in columns are $0$ for $U$.

Comment: ok, I have one doubt more. What for non-squared matrices? I mean, when $\Sigma$ is non-squared, can we multiply anything on the right to get an identity? If we don't, can't $U$ has anything in at least one row (because 'the zero rest' of the identity will always make zeros)?

Comment: @Yelon We did not assume that $\Sigma$ is squared. As long as it has independent rows, it has a right inverse, because then $\Sigma$ would be a surjection. I think you can find this result ("theorem") in linear algebra textbooks.

Comment: I don't know you understand my point :D

Let $\Sigma=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\alpha_1&0\\0&\alpha_2\\0&0\end{array}\right]$. I guess, that whatever would we put on the right to multiply by sigma, we'll get
$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\0&0&0\end{array}\right]$, because the last row in $\Sigma$ has only zeros. I'm not sure if instead of $c,f$ can stand only zeros, but I don't see how we can get $1$ in the right corner to get the identity matrix.

Comment: @Yelon In your example, $\Sigma$ does NOT have linearly independent rows. What the theorem says is all matrices with linearly independent rows have right inverse.